# Why do I need to click the Page number before I get the data first?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mern

So I'm rendering filtered products, and now I want to create pagination. It is working but I need to click a page number first before it shows up. I already included a loading state, but it's not working properly.

My data is coming from the backend MongoDB

**This is my first render**:
[image: First Render]

**After Clicking page 1**
[image]

```
const ProductList = ({products, category}) => {
  const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts]  = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() =>{
    const isAvailable = products.filter((product) => product.quantity !== 0 )
    setFilteredProducts(isAvailable)
    setLoading(false)
  },[setFilteredProducts, category,products])




  const firstIndex = 0
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(5)
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
  const [data,setData] = useState(filteredProducts.slice(firstIndex, pageSize))

  useEffect(() =>{
    setData(filteredProducts.slice(0, pageSize))
    setLoading(false)
  },[pageSize])


  const handleChange = (event, value) => {
    setPage(value);
    setData(filteredProducts.slice(firstIndex + pageSize * (value - 1), pageSize * value));
  };


  return (
    <>
    {loading ?
      <BeatLoader 
      color="#36d7b7" 
      loading={loading}
      size={50}
      aria-label="Loading Spinner"
      data-testid="loader"
      />
      :
      (
        <Box sx={{backgroundColor: '#f5f5f5', display:'flex', marginTop:2}}>
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <Typography sx={{textAlign: 'center', paddingY: '20px', fontWeight: 700, color: '#212121', typography: {xs: "h6", md: "h4"}}}>Products</Typography>
          <Box sx={{display: 'flex', alignItems:'center',justifyContent: 'space-evenly', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: '10px'}}>
            {data.map((product) => (
              <ProductItem  key={product._id} product={product} />
              ))}
          </Box>
          <Pagination 
            sx={{display: 'flex', alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center',margin: 4}}
            size="large"
            count={Math.ceil(filteredProducts.length/pageSize)}
            page={page}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
      </Container>
    </Box>
    )
  }
  </>
  )
}

export default ProductList
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the second `useEffect` is using the value of `filteredProducts` but not having it in the dependencies array, so it could not update `data` when it is ready or if it changes.

This seems to be the reason `data` could only be updated with the `handleChange` event.

To fix this, try add `filteredProducts` to the dependencies array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setData(filteredProducts.slice(0, pageSize));
  setLoading(false);
  //  Add this here
}, [filteredProducts, pageSize]);
```

There might be other issues that need to be addressed, but hope that this still helps.

As for `loading`, not too sure but it seems to start as `true` but is immateriality set to `false` as soon as `useEffect` runs. If this component is not toggling the `loading` value, it might not need to be a state.

Perhaps consider to render the spinner based on condition, for example if `product` is empty `[]` (usually it is when the data is being fetched).

Alternatively perhaps handle a `loading` state in the parent component where the data is fetched could also work, such as `{loading ? <Spinner /> : <ProductList />}`.